# ZF2. if I have literal route - will it also catch a url with GET params or not?

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm a bit confused about params in ZF2 routing. Here's the literal route:

```
 'route-test1' => array(
        'type' => 'literal',
        'options' => array(
            'route' => '/my/route',
            'defaults' => array(
                'controller' => 'IndexController',
                'action'     => 'myRoute',
           ),
      ),
 ),
```

Should that route catch only:

```
example.com/my/route
```

Or also:

```
example.com/my/route?test1=aaa&test2=bbb    
example.com/my/route?test=aaa
```

**RESOLUTION:**

Tested id (dunno why I haven't done it int he first place) - and yes - it will match all of these urls - with or without query line.

Comment: Yes, a literal route will match URIs regardless of query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Then you can access the arguments (from a controller, for example) with:

```
$this->getRequest()->getQuery()
```